# android - (HttpURLConnection) downloading image from internet

Tags: android, genymotion, android-internet

I want to create a simple android app that retrieves an image from the internet
The Activity code looks like this :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BitmapDemo extends ActionBarActivity {
    //bikin objek image view nya
    ImageView imageview;

    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        Koneksi koneksi = new Koneksi();  //class untuk koneksi nya

        try{
            in = koneksi.OpenHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bitmap_demo);

        //download image nya
        //Bitmap bitmap = downloadImage("http://10.0.3.2/mp/tux2.jpeg");  //localhost
        Bitmap bitmap = downloadImage("http://infinitejest.wallacewiki.com/david-foster-wallace/images/a/ab/Nasa_Emblem.jpg");  //localhost
        //Bitmap bitmap = downloadImage("nama saya luki");  //localhost
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

And for the connection, i created a class called Koneksi.java (called in the activity on line 22

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

//import org.apache.http.HttpConnection;

public class Koneksi {
    public InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)){
            throw new IOException("String yang dimasukkan bukan alamat web");
        }

                try{
                    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpCon.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpCon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpCon.connect();

                    //apakah respon berhasil
                    response = httpCon.getResponseCode();
                    if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){  //sama dengan 200 ga ya
                        in = httpCon.getInputStream();
                    }
                }

                catch(Exception ex){
                    //ex.printStackTrace();
                    throw new IOException("koneksi error");
                }

        return in; 
    }
}
```

When i execute the app, the catch on Koneksi.java throws, saying "koneksi error". Am i missing something?

Note : i have already add "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" and also "android.permission.INTERNET" in the manifest

Comment: What is the value of `response `?

Comment: uncomment `ex.printStackTrace();` in catch block and see in logcat what it prints.

Comment: Without logcat, I can just tell you that mostly its NetworkOnMainThread exception. You need to use AsyncTask for performing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the permissions. Fine. But you **need to** create AsyncTask for performing this.

You are trying to access Network on main thread.

Change your Koneksi class to an AsyncTask:

```
private class Koneksi extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>  {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //your code for downloading image    
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //handle result
    }
}
```

Call it as:

```
new Koneksi().execute(params);  //params is a String array of input if any.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A fast and easy way for you:

```
    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    private String url;
    public MyRunnable (String _url){
        url=_url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Bitmap bitmap;
        InputStream in = null;
        Koneksi koneksi = new Koneksi();  //class untuk koneksi nya

        try{
            in = koneksi.OpenHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        BitmapDemo.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in your code:

```
private Bitmap downloadImage(String url){
    Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(url));
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can not open a network connection from the main-thread. 
The user interface runs on the main-thread, so every connection will interrupt the interface and you can't do anything while the download is performed.

You have to build a helper class, which connects in the background and does a callback when the download finished.

See here: [Perform Network Operations on a Separate Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)